# codeBlock wrapped in <pre> inside contenteditable breaks on pressing Enter

Tags: javascript, dom-events, contenteditable, execcommand

In my custom-editor wrapping up the code in `<pre>` tags works fine. I would like to visually organize the pasted code for better readability. For that I need blank lines in between chunks of code. But instead of a empty line, when I press Enter, the whole code block breaks into two, with new one wrapped in its own pre-tag. The code below is supposed to be in a single-block with an empty line between `example_function` and `another_example_function()`

[image: precode issue]

**FYI**, the `contenteditable` class is set to have `style="display:inline-block"` to prevent `div.wrapper` on every line. Possibly relevant CSS info - `pre { white-space: pre-wrap;}`. I am on chrome 83.xx. Let me know if you need any more info. Below is what I tried and failed:

```js
//there could be several code-blocks so running a loop to get all
let preTags = document.querySelector('.custom_editor').querySelectorAll('pre')
if (preTags) {
  preTags.forEach(function(item) { // attaching an event-listener to each code block
    item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) { //on enter just need a empty new line
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<br>');
        return false;
      }
    })
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content" style="display:inline-block;" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior. Could you provide an example of the HTML code that you have?

Comment: @padaleiana I have added the html code now. I already mentioned about the only difference from normal that - the style attribute i have is `style="display:inline-block;".`. And I did that else it was wrapping up every line within div. It is more difficult to work if your editor wraps every line with div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested pretags eg. `contenteditable>pre` do not seem like an ideal setup for events like `'keypress'`, `'keydown'` and `'keyup'` as they did respond to these events in my case. The `'click'` event within pretags worked but did not process the `if (e.key === 'Enter')` check, so I did not follow that route.

Instead of listening to events for each pretag, I attached a listener to the container only and all of sudden my custom setting for enter-event was working inside and outside all pretags within container. Eventually I can get the empty lines within my pretags on pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

```
document.querySelector('.custom_editor').addEventListener('keypress', someFunc)
function someFunc(e){
    if (e.key === 'Enter') { 
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, "<br>");
        e.preventDefault()
    } 
}
```